# Iphone “ringing” in the middle of the night in do not Disturb mode

Tags: iphone

I have sleep time/do not Disturb on every night. 
This morning at 2:30am I was woken up by the ringtone “Opening default” going off on my lock screen with no push notification.

Nothing has that ringtone set in sounds. There are no missed calls or apps that used it. It’s freaking me out.

Device: iphone 7 plus
Fw: 12.4.1

There was no alarm set at this time. Any ideas???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  It's clear that something set that off.  When you're on the lock screen, slide your finger up and see if any notifications are displayed.

Comment: There are no push notifications as per the original post. There was no indication anything had set off at all. It was making a racket which didn’t stop until I unlocked the phone.

Comment: Are you sure DND was turned on as scheduled (moon icon displayed)?  Do you have 'Allow Calls From' turned on?  It's very difficult to determine what set it off.